# azure function apps not showing in azure portal

Tags: python, azure, function, azureportal

Azure functions are deployed successfully from the terminal.  There is no CI/CD involved in deployment. I am using http triggers with python. I do see `init.py, function.json, host.json` in the app files. However, the functions are not listed on the function apps section in the Azure portal.  Looked into the all suggestions above and nothing helped so far. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you name your file `init.py` or `__init__.py`? Azure Functions is looking for an `__init__.py` file.

The directory structure should be like:

```
<project_root>/
| <function_one_name>/
| | __init__.py
| | function.json
| <function_two_name>/
| | ...
...
| host.json
| settings.json
| requirements.txt
| .funcignore
```

Comment: it is `__init__.py` my function.json has the following: `
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger"
`

Comment: solved. I published from the incorrect directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `az login` is set to proper Cloud and subscription. I've seen publish fails from VS, vscode without `az login` thru CLI
2. Try deploying with Azure CLI [functionapp publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration&tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash#deploy-the-function-project-to-azure)

   ```
   func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>
   ```