# Unable to explain why my Python based Azure Function is not appearing when using GitHub actions to deploy

Tags: python, azure-functions, github-actions

I don't seem to be able to diagnose why my python based azure function (deployed via github actions) is not appearing in the azure function list.  Something subtle is causing it to not be processed

I have successfully deployed my python script using github actions (see pic1).
[image]

I have been able to successfully see the app files visible within my azure function (see pic2).

[image]

And yet I am unable to see my function within the functions list (see pic3).
[image]

I feel like if I just had the ability to see what or how Azure is processing my files, to see if there's a problem with some configuration OR modules OR something then I would have a starting point.  But right now it feels like a blackbox and I don't know what methodology to follow to figure out what's wrong.

I feel like there is something simple missing OR misconfigured, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the Azure Function Deployment with Github actions and it was successful.

Initially, When I deployed the Function it was not visible, Refer below:-

[image]

Make sure your init.py and function.json is inside one directory and other files are outside that directory for the deployment to work successfully, Refer below:-

Reference:- [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035303/azure-function-apps-not-showing-in-azure-portal) answer by jsprovoke

[image]

Now, I deployed the Function with Github action and the Function was visible in the Portal refer below:-

**Refer my complete github workflow in this [**Link**](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - siliconfunc12

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.10' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'siliconfunc12'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_E640D92BF68849679F8A36682B022D5F }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Python Function HTTPTrigger visible in Portal like below:-***

[image]

Add the settings below to run your function app from Zip:-

[image]

HTTPTrigger ran successfully like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can directly run your Function app deployment from Deployment center with Github that will automatically create Github workflow and deploy your Function Trigger to Function app, Refer below:-

[image]

Comment: Please format the attached workflow properly. Invalid formatting makes a GHA workflow invalid. Looks like a copy/paste issue. You may use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to fix such issues. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for your recommendation, I've edited the workflow accordingly.

Comment: That's awesome - that fixed my problem.  Now the timer is just not starting.  A different new problem.  The first time you create a timer function do you need to do something to activate the timer?

{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "extraction_trigger",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */2 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: After the timer trigger runs, It will be activated based on the CRON schedule you provided. Refer this quickstart - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function and this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process and this Github issue on Timer trigger failing to start - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/224

Comment: @steambun what exactly was the issue, and what exactly fixed it?

Comment: The issue what the directory structure.  I had multiple Functions with a large python app and I ultimately had to change the structure of my python project to assist.